# When is a real algebraic (non-projective) variety a Kähler manifold?

Tags: kahler-manifolds

By an (real) algebraic variety (non-projective), I assume what is meant is the surface given by the solutions to a set of polynomial equations:

$$f_n(x_1,x_2,\dotsc)=0.$$

Assume $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$.

When is this a Kähler manifold?

Is there a known condition on the set of functions $f_n$ that can determine if the manifold is Kähler or not?

For example, I know one case which I believe to be a Kähler manifold, that is the torus. For example, embedded in 4 dimensions, it is given by the set of equations:

\begin{gather*}
x^2+y^2-1 = 0 \\
z^2+w^2-1 = 0.
\end{gather*}

My first idea was that a Kähler manifold would be any complex algebraic variety. i.e. replace $f$ with complex analytic functions. But I am told this is only Kähler in complex **projective** space. I am only interested in manifolds embedded in Euclidean space. (Since I don't know how to do differential geometry in projective space!)

So what are the conditions on $f$ (the function in real space) that make the manifold Kähler? i.e. given a random set of polynomials how do we determine if it is a Kähler manifold or not?

Comment: An initial note: by Nash-Tognoli, *every* smooth manifold is diffeomorphic to a real algebraic variety. So you're starting from a very wide class (basically all smooth manifolds).

Comment: @KevinCasto But surely that condition is only for complex projective space. Yes, its a hard question. That's why I asked :)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen But what about the torus? That is Kahler and I've written down it's equations in Euclidean space. Perhaps it means it *can* be defined projectively but doesn't have to be??? The link only refers to *complex* algebraic varities. It doesn't say a real algebraic variety can't be Kahler.

Comment: @KevinCasto OK. But the question is not to write a kahler manifold as a set of equations. The question is to do the reverse, determine when a set of equations is a kahler manifold. I don't get your point??? If your point is that you can transform the affine equations into complex projective space to determine that it is Kahler, perhaps that would constitute an answer if there was an algorithm to do this?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Sorry that is not my intent. I will edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Sorry, I was responding to Bret, who has deleted his comments. I guess I would say that it seems hopeless, given a random set of polynomials, to do anything 'algorithmic' with them to determine if the resulting real algebraic variety is Kahler. See e.g.: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/99581/recognizing-kahler-manifolds-of-complex-dimension-n

Comment: How about taking a set of complex polynomials defined in projective space. Is it equally hard to transform them into a set of real equations in Euclidean space? I guess this is also very hard.

Comment: Kahler manifolds aren't always projective...

Comment: @KevinCasto: N-T is only for compact manifolds. It has an improvement, due to Akbulut and King, that every smooth **tame** manifold can be realized as a smooth real-algebraic set.